# combine two words into one on Vector search pinecone

Tags: openai-api, langchain, pinecone

I have a pdf document of 600 pages, the document has regulations listed from 1 to 30 when I try to query "What is regulation 1" or "what is regulation 7" or " what is regulation  8" I get a relative answers but when I try to query "what is regulation 25" or "what is regulation 17", what happens is the vector search searches for a regulation keyword and give me the response(k=4), it does not search "regulation 25" even if I increase k value it is not helping, Is there a way to combine the search of two words during vector search

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a semi-structured data problem. If I understand this correctly, you're able to ingest data from the PDF file into your Pinecone vector database. From there, you can retrieve the top-k chunks and see some results; however, the retriever is unable to fetch the correct results. All in all, you want to be able to match a query like "What is regulation 25" with a direct match on "Regulation 25" in the ingested document?

There are several ways to approach a problem like this. One method is to perform pre-processing on the data during the chunking, embedding, and ingestion processes. For instance, you might replace semi-structured data elements such as tables, diagrams, page numbers, etc., with more meaningful representations for your application. This could be similar to what named-entity recognition does for unstructured text, classifying named entities and thereby annotating the text.

Another, simpler approach is to utilize metadata filtering or namespaces with your ingested data in the vector database. With [metadata filtering](https://docs.pinecone.io/docs/metadata-filtering), you can attach metadata key-value pairs when ingesting your data into the vector database. With [namespaces](https://docs.pinecone.io/docs/namespaces#using-namespaces), you can segment the data into their own distinct areas. Here's some examples from Pinecone, adding metadata to vectors you insert:

```
import pinecone

pinecone.init(api_key="your-api-key", environment="us-west1-gcp")
index = pinecone.Index("example-index")

index.upsert([
    ("A", [0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1], {"genre": "comedy", "year": 2020}),
    ("B", [0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2], {"genre": "documentary", "year": 2019}),
    ("C", [0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3], {"genre": "comedy", "year": 2019}),
    ("D", [0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4], {"genre": "drama"}),
    ("E", [0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5], {"genre": "drama"})
])
```

Querying with metadata filters:

```
index.query(
    vector=[0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1],
    filter={
        "genre": {"$eq": "documentary"},
        "year": 2019
    },
    top_k=1,
    include_metadata=True
)
```